# Android Studio roboguice.xml syntax errors

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I've referenced roboguice 2.0 in my new Android project build with Android Studio, here is my `build.gradle` file:

```
        buildscript {
            repositories {
                mavenCentral()
            }
            dependencies {
                classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.2'
            }
        }

        apply plugin: 'android-library'

        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }

        dependencies {
            compile files('/libs/android-support-v4.jar')

            compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:2.0'
        }

        android {
            compileSdkVersion 17
            buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

            defaultConfig {
                minSdkVersion 10
                targetSdkVersion 16
            }
        }
```

Both `gradle clean` and `gradle build` run successfully but the IDE is reporting the error `Element resources must be declared` in `roboguice.xml`

Am I missing something or is this a bug in the IDE?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend Android Studio as it is pre-release software.

Answer (score 1):

Mystery solved,

I've accidentally copied `roboguice.xml` to `res/menu` instead of `res/values`